# Iterate over Java object methods with no args and non-void return type and print toString return value (for debugging)

Tags: java, debugging, reflection, dump

I would like to dump content of complex Java objects for debugging purpose.

For example I want to dump of `toString()` from return value of all `get...()` methods of `HttpServletRequest` object.

I am not interested in fields but rather in methods return values.

I am not sure if it's possible with `commons-beanutils` or `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString()`

Currently I implemented with `Introspector` core API:

```
public static String dump(Object obj, String regex) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(obj.getClass());
        for (MethodDescriptor descr : info.getMethodDescriptors()) {
            String name = descr.getName();
            Method method = descr.getMethod();
            if ( ! name.matches(regex))
                continue;
            if (method.getParameterCount() > 0)
                continue;
            if (Stream.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType()))
                continue;
            Object objValue = method.invoke(obj);
            String strValue = Optional.ofNullable(objValue).map(Object::toString).orElse("null");
            logger.info("name: {}, value: {}", name, strValue);
            sb.append(name);
            sb.append(" => ");
            sb.append(strValue);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

but I would like to use something standard and flexible...

Comment: Your code is already using “something standard and flexible”. You may ask yourself whether it is worth going the `Introspector` detour, instead of just iterating over `obj.getClass().getMethods()`; using `Introspector` is only useful if you assume that there might be explicit `BeanInfo`s with more meta information. Besides that, `Optional.ofNullable(objValue).map(Object::toString).orElse( "null")` is a verbose way of getting the same as `String.valueOf(objValue)` and you can simply catch `ReflectiveOperationException` instead of that long list.

Comment: @Holger What I found annoying is that some object shouldn't be converted to String, like Stream or Socket or other IO/state objects. If someone made safe code I would like to use it instead of mine hackish.

Comment: That decision can’t come for free. E.g., I’d probably think, that `Socket` instances should be included in the string representation. Besides that, asking for software libraries, etc. is considered off topic…

Comment: OK. Some `toString()` methods damage state of object and collecting list of such types is cumbersome

Comment: There should be no `toString()` methods which damage the state of object. That could be clearly considered to be a bug of that particular `toString()` method implementation. If you have types with such methods in your application/library, how would another 3rd party library know about them, without having you to collect and specify these types?